# Detecting repeated sequence of same elements at the end of a list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, data-structures, graph, cycle

I have a list of binary numbers (converted to strings) in a list. I want to detect if the list ends in a cycle or not, i.e if an ongoing repeating sequence of same numbers is detected when the list ends.

For example, the list `["1101", "1001", "1010", "1010", "1010", "0011", "0011", "1111", "1110", "0111", "1101", "1010", "0101", "1101", "1010", "0101", "1101", "1010", "0101", "1101"]` ends with a cycle of repeating `"1101", "1010", "0101"`

Also all of the binary numbers are of the same fixed length (4 here), and the length of the list is also fixed (20 in this case), if that helps. Another catch is that there might be repetitions of the same binary number, which are not considered cycle. I think I should just filter the list before processing so that there is no consecutive same number in the list, but I'm not sure if that'll help.

The code I have tried so far looks like:

```
def detect_cycle(arr: list) -> bool:
    """Should return True iff there is an ongoing cycle at the end of the list. Cycle here can be defined as a repeated sequence
    that appears in the list in the same order multiple times consecutively.

    :param list arr: The list in which cycle has to be detected.
    :return bool: Returns True iff a cycle is detected at the end of the list, False otherwise.
    """
    res = False
    arr_len = len(arr)
    rev_arr = list(reversed(arr))
    for rev_ix, elem in enumerate(rev_arr):
        if rev_ix == arr_len // 2 + 1 or res:
            break
        for i in range(arr_len // 2):
            if rev_arr[rev_ix : rev_ix + i] == rev_arr[rev_ix + i : rev_ix + 2 * i]:
                res = True
    return res
```

But this function is returning a lot of False positives. Any way to fix and/ or optimize this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The binary representations could be just regarded as 16 different letters (hex digits, or some other convention). So we can look at strings of such characters. What if that string is "A01234567A0", is that considered a repetition of "A01234567", or is there some rule that at least one repetition should be a complete repetition?

Comment: No. The binary numbers are of fixed length. So however you convert it to hex, it should give you the same result. However, I am trying to do string comparison, and not sure how converting to hex helps here.

Comment: OK, I still have a doubt about my question: what exactly do you consider a repetition? Is ["0000", "1111", "0000"] something that has repetition?

Comment: *"Also all of the binary numbers are of the same fixed length (4 here), and the length of the list is also fixed (20 in this case)"* When you say "in this case", do you mean "in this small example" or do you mean in your actual true situation? Because 20 is a very small number, so even a terribly naive algorithm would perform well on a list of size 20.

Comment: You can fix your code by changing: (1) `for i in range(arr_len // 2):` into `for i in range(2, arr_len // 2 + 1):` (no need to test with i=1, since you said a repetition of a single number doesn't count); (2) `rev_arr[rev_ix : rev_ix + i] == rev_arr[rev_ix + i : rev_ix + 2 * i]` into `rev_arr[0:i] == rev_arr[i:i+i]`; (3) `res = True` into `return True` because there is no need to keep iterating if you've found a positive; (4) and finally, remove the whole `for rev_ix, elem in enumerate(rev_arr):` loop, I don't even understand what it's for.

Comment: @Stef I was trying to say that in this case of a small example, it is 20. In some cases of my algorithm, this length can go upto 2048 and the binary number length can go upto 15.

Comment: @trincot I would not consider `["0000", "1111", "0000"]` as a cycle, but would consider it a cycle if the list ends with `["0000", "1111", "0000", "1111"]`. The reason being that the first example does not complete the second loop of the cycle, thus not repeating both the numbers in the cycle.

Comment: @Stef Sorry about the misunderstanding there. Initially I was testing if there is any cycle detected in the list, but then the requirement changed to only the end. That's why the stray `for rev_ix, elem in enumerate(rev_arr)` loop was still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is setting `res` to True when just one equality comparison succeeds. Yet it is clear that you need a whole series of comparisons to be equal before you could decide there is a cycle.

You could compare slices like this:

```
def detect_cycle(arr: list) -> bool:
    return any(arr[-i:] == arr[-2*i:-i] for i in range(2, len(arr) // 2 + 1))
```

#### Example

Taking the input from the question:

```
["1101", "1001", "1010", "1010", "1010", "0011", "0011", "1111", "1110", "0111", "1101", "1010", "0101", "1101", "1010", "0101", "1101", "1010", "0101", "1101"]
```

This code has `i` going from 2 to half of the size of the input, and `-i` and `-2*i` are used as boundaries for slices.

When `i` is 2, this compares `arr[-2:]` with `arr[-4:-2]`, when `i` is 3, it compares `arr[-3:]` with `arr[-6:-3]`, ...etc, as in this table:

| `i` | `arr[-i:]` | `arr[-2*i:-i]` | equal? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | `["0101", "1101"]` | `["1101", "1010"]` | No |
| 3 | `["1010", "0101", "1101"]` | `["1010", "0101", "1101"]` | Yes |

The `any` function will stop further iterations when it has found an equality, so in this example the iteration stops and `True` is returned.

If none of the compared slices are equal then `any` will return `False`.

Comment: Could you please explain how this is working? I can see this is working for most cases, but I don't understand how!

Comment: If there are cases for which it doesn't work, could you please inform me about them? Can you indicate what exactly I need to explain here? Is it the `any` call? Or the slicing with `[-i:]`?

Comment: I understand the `any()` call, but did not understand how the array slicing is able to compare all possible cycle lengths, along with ignoring any stray value left from the cycle! But your explanation has made it pretty clear. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are no "cycles" in a (array-style) list, so you are using this word in an unconventional way.  I don't think you've defined it sufficiently, so I don't want to write too much in case I end up answering the wrong question.  But...

If you want to test to see if the list could be divided into 3 parts such that the last two parts are equal, then you can do this in linear time:

1. Reverse the list
2. Begin a [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) search for an instance of the reversed list within itself, starting at element 1.
3. If, at any time in the search, the number of matched elements is at least half of the search position, then you've found a prefix of the reversed list that repeats.  This implies a repeat at the end of the original list.

Comment: I understand there is no cycle in an array. But this array is basically a representation of a path in a graph with the nodes being the binary numbers. Also, your idea sounds correct. I want to know if the list can be divided into 3 parts, with the last two parts being equal.